# Lucene 4.0 API - NRTManager simple case usage

Tags: java, lucene

I'm literally struggling with this new API and the lack of examples for core things like the NRT Manager.

I followed [this](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html) example and here is the final result:

This is how the NRT Manager is built:

```
analyzer = new StopAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);
writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(new File(ConfigUtil.getProperty("lucene.directory"))), config);
mgrWriter = new NRTManager.TrackingIndexWriter(writer);
ReferenceManager<IndexSearcher> mgr = new NRTManager(mgrWriter, new SearcherFactory(), true);
```

Adding a new element to the NRT Manager's writer:

```
long gen = -1;
try{
    Document userDoc = DocumentManager.getDocument(user);
    gen = mgrWriter.addDocument(userDoc);
} catch (Exception e) {}
return gen;
```

After some small amount of time I need to update the previous document:

```
// Acquire a searcher from the NRTManager. I am using the generation obtained in the creation step
((NRTManager)mgr).waitForGeneration(gen);
searcher = mgr.acquire();

//Search for the document based on some user id
Term idTerm = new Term(USER_ID, Integer.toString(userId));
Query idTermQuery = new TermQuery(term);
TopDocs result = searcher.search(idTermQuery, 1);
if (result.totalHits > 0) resultDoc = searcher.doc(result.scoreDocs[0].doc);
else resultDoc = null;
```

The problem is that `resultDoc` will always be null. What am I missing? I should not use `commit()` or `flush()` in orther to see those changes.

I am using a `NRTManagerReopenThread` as exemplified [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NRTManagerReopenThread.html).

**LE userDoc creation**

```
public static Document getDocument(User user) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    FieldType storedType = new FieldType();
    storedType.setStored(true);
    storedType.setIndexed(false);

    // Store user data
    doc.add(new Field(USER_ID, user.getId().toString(), storedType));
    doc.add(new Field(USER_NAME, user.getFirstName() + user.getLastName(), storedType));

    FieldType unstoredType = new FieldType();
    unstoredType.setStored(false);
    unstoredType.setIndexed(true);
    Field field = null;

    // Analyze Location
    String tokens = "";
    if (user.getLocation() != null && ! user.getLocation().isEmpty()){
        for (Tag location : user.getLocation()) tokens += location.getName() + " ";

        field = new Field(USER_LOCATION, tokens, unstoredType);
        field.setBoost(Constants.LOCATION);
        doc.add(field);
    }

    // Analyze Language
    if (user.getLanguage() != null && ! user.getLanguage().isEmpty()){
        // Same as Location
}

    // Analyze Career
    if (user.getCareer() != null && ! user.getCareer().isEmpty()){
        // Same as Location
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: What is IndexAccess? How are getManagerWriter and acquire implemented? Where is mgrWriter instantiated? Could you provide a self-contained example with no depencendy except Lucene that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @jpountz hi! I edited the code. I hope it clear enough now.

Comment: It works perfectly here. How is userDoc created?

Comment: @jpountz Hi again! Thanks for your time! I posted the `getDocument()` implementation. The most important thing there is that the field named `USER_ID` (this is the field searched with the `NRT` afterwords). I intended it to be `Stored` and `Not Analysed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not NRT-related. You are searching agains the USER_ID field although it has not been indexed, this can't work. If you don't want your ID field to be tokenized, just call FieldType#setTokenized(false) (or just use StringField, which does exactly that by default: indexed by not tokenized).